# How can i exit 'if block' in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want Exit if block on C#
when condition is true
how can i do that?

Here is Code Example

```
string str = "Hello World"

void func(bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB)
{
    if(isCheckA)
    {
        if(isCheckB)
        {
            // Exit if Block
        }

        str = "Bye World"
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

if isCheckA is true and isCheckB is true
str is not changed

the bool value A and B must be checked separately by if

Comment: Just check for `isCheckA && !isCheckB` then.

Comment: Right.  You can't "exit an if block".  You could do `if( !isCheckB )` and put the rest of the `if` in there, but Sweeper's answer is better.

Comment: In general, either `if(!isCheckB){...code...}` or `}else{ ...code... }` there is no exit. Though since your simplified example doesn't included any code between the if tests, just combine them.

Comment: You _could_ use a `do/while` block and use `break` to exit.

Comment: enclose `str = "Bye World";` with `else { str = "Bye World"; }`

Comment: Why "the bool value A and B must be checked separately by if"?

Answer (score 2):

These seem like your clear choices to me:

(1) use `else`

```
void func(bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB)
{
    if (isCheckA)
    {
        if (isCheckB)
        { }
        else
            str = "Bye World";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

(2) use `!`

```
void func(bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB)
{
    if (isCheckA)
    {
        if (!isCheckB)
        {
            str = "Bye World";
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Comment: Option 1 is painful. 

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama - Agreed, but it is the simplest refactoring of the OP's code that I could think of - at least to keep the same structure.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm more concerned about the inconsistent use of braces and line-breaks in an `if` statement.

Comment: @Dai - I tend to put empty curly braces on the same line to make sure that they are obviously empty and that they form a single empty statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to try early return strategy. This strategy prevents from having nested multiple level 'IF'. Makes your code easy to read. Of course it depends on requirements, but if there is possibility I'm using it.

```
void func(bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB)
{
    if(!isCheckA)
    {
        Console.Writeline("First condition failed. Exiting");
        return;
    }
    
    if(isCheckB)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second condition is true. Exiting");
        return;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine("Bye World");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[C# allows the use of `goto` for local jumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements) like this:

```cs
void func( bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB )
{
    if( isCheckA )
    {
        if( isCheckB )
        {
            goto afterIf; // https://xkcd.com/292/
        }

        str = "Bye World"
    }
    
afterIf:
    Console.WriteLine( str );
}
```

Or you can use `break` provided you have a dummy outer loop (which won't run its body more than once):

```cs
void func( bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB )
{
    do
    {
        if( isCheckA )
        {
            if( isCheckB )
            {
                break;
            }

            str = "Bye World"
        }
    }
    while( false );

    Console.WriteLine( str );
}
```

Or a local method:

```cs
void func( bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB )
{
    void innerFunc()
    {
        if( isCheckA )
        {
            if( isCheckB )
            {
                return;
            }

            str = "Bye World"
        }
    }
    innerFunc();

    Console.WriteLine( str );
}
```

---

Though I'm sure everyone will agree you should do just this instead:

```cs
void func( bool isCheckA, bool isCheckB )
{
    if( isCheckA && !isCheckB )
    {
        str = "Bye World"
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine( str );
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the code sample given was greatly simplified, and it was more a case of a guard condition before a much longer code. Sometimes you just want to get a few checks out of the way first, and not increase your nesting level. That said, you can also get much the same effect by putting the inner block into a separate method, and using `return` instead of `goto` for each check you want to exit from.

Comment: You should make some dislaimer about not using `goto` in these cases. Although OP *could* do it that way, he/she *shouldn't*.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain nah, it's funnier this way

Comment: maybe, but that Isn't a good indicator for a good answer, IMHO.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain This QA has already been downvoted to `-2` - if I'm going to waste my time posting answers that will end-up deleted in a week anyway I may as well have fun doing it.

Comment: I like the fact you went from the most horrific way to the most obvious, however I think that the fact the OP have asked the question probably means that whatever these two conditions are, there's a need for refactoring there, probably extract to two different methods. I'm kind of surprised no one mentioned it.